# How to simplify the code?

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to find values?

```
let arrData = [[1, 0], [74, 0], [75, 1], [76, 1], [79, 1], [80, 0], [81, 0], [82, 0], [83, 1], [84, 0], [85, 0], [86, 0]];
let isn = 75;

function searchCount(arr, isn) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i][0] == isn){
            return arr[i][1];
        }
    }
}

console.log(searchCount(arrData, isn));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The **`find()`** method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is returned.

```js
let arrData = [[1, 0], [74, 0], [75, 1], [76, 1], [79, 1], [80, 0], [81, 0], [82, 0], [83, 1], [84, 0], [85, 0], [86, 0]];
let isn = 75;

function searchCount(arr, isn) {
    var el = arr.find(a => a[0] === isn);
    return el && el[1];
}

console.log(searchCount(arrData, isn));
```

Or use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects)

> The **`Map`** object is a simple key/value map. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

in combination with [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)

> The **`get()`** method returns a specified element from a `Map` object.

```js
let arrData = [[1, 0], [74, 0], [75, 1], [76, 1], [79, 1], [80, 0], [81, 0], [82, 0], [83, 1], [84, 0], [85, 0], [86, 0]];
let isn = 75;

function searchCount(arr, isn) {
    return (new Map(arr)).get(isn);
}

console.log(searchCount(arrData, isn));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert to a dictionary as below :

```
var dataMap = 
    arrData.reduce(function(p, c) { p[c[0]] = c[1]; return p; }, {});
```

You could use dataMap to search by passing the item to search as an index to dataMap:

```
dataMap[75]
```